# Imagemagick: Create multiple borders

Tags: imagemagick

How do I create an image with multiple borders in imagemagick?

```
.------------.
|            |
| .--------. |
| |        | |
| |        | |
| '-----b1-' |
|            |
'---------b2-'
```

`b1` and `b2` are different borders with different properties. For example `b1` can be 1px red and `b2` 10px blue.

**Edit:** Could it be done without creating an intermediate image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be explained here: http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/crop/#border .

For two borders you may run IM twice.

Comment: It could be done without creating an intermediate image, http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-processing.php ~ like this `$magick> convert rose: gif:- | convert - -resize "200%" bigrose.jpg`

Answer (score 3):

Sure, like this:

```
convert wizard: -bordercolor red -border 5 -bordercolor blue -border 10 result.jpg
```

[image]